# how to pass a Bunifu ProgressBar to a function that has Windows ProgressBar parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a function

```
 private void addToGanttChart(ProgressBar pgBar)
 {
    //do some stuff ...
 }
```

and then I'm going to pass a ProgressBar on that function

```
 addToGantt(pgBar10) //pgBar10 is using Bunifu Framework
```

my problem is that VS gives an error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: additional tag: Bunifu-Framework

Comment: Short answer: you can't. There's too little information for a workaround, like where does addToGanttChart() come from, can you alter/extend that?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, sorry for that. the addToGranttChart() is a custom function that I just made. I have a some code there that I want to execute.

Comment: Then change the parameter to the correct (Bunifu) type. But I suspect that will just move the error around...

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I already figured this out. I just add the namespace of the bunifu framework to the parameter. in my case its "ns1" so the parameter is now 
     addToGanttChart(ns1.ProgressBar pgBar)
     {
     }